# How to specify property value in range?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have to create a relationship between two nodes where node2 stores a certain range value i.e 3-40 and node1 stores certain value i.e 5.

I have to build relationship between node1 and node2 only if node1 value lies in range of node2 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume `Foo` nodes contain the `value` property, and `Range` nodes contain the `min` and `max` properties.

This query would find all `Foo` nodes whose `value` property is in the `[min .. max]` range of a specified `Range` node, and then create the `IS_IN_RANGE` relationship between them:

```
MATCH (r:Range {id: 123}), (n:Foo)
WHERE r.min <= n.value <= r.max
CREATE (n)-[:IS_IN_RANGE]->(r)
```